# How to take entire database Store Procedure Scripts

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

How to take entire database store procedures full scripts same as the MS SQL 2008 R2 Generate Script feature. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the complete DDL statements for each function that is owned by the current user in the schema public:

```
select pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)||';'
from pg_proc p
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
  join pg_user u on u.usesysid = p.proowner
where n.nspname = 'public'
  and p.prokind <> 'a'
  and u.usename = current_user;
```

`prokind <> 'a'` is necessary because `pg_get_functiondef()` doesn't work with user defined aggregate functions.

If you want the functions from a different schema or owner, just change the `where` conditions accordingly.

You can spool the output to a file to get a SQL script containing all functions.